# json string decoding for array

Tags: php, json

My code is as below.

```
            $code = json_decode($json,true);
    var_dump($code);
    echo "1";
    echo "Numbers of tweets containing this link : $code->{'count'}"; //some issue here  line (x)
```

but
        var_dump($code);
gives:

```
array (size=2)
  'count' => int 1602
  'url' => string 'http://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=yOutxpoXnfg' (length=43)
```

what is wrong with my code?
line x does not show any thing.

Comment: It's an array. Use `$code['count'];`

Comment: @FDL: that also does not work

Comment: then you are using it incorrectly. See the answer from Sudhir, that is how you need to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`true` converts to associative array format for [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode), so change to:

```
echo "Numbers of tweets containing this link :". $code['count'];
```